# How can I post an array on ngModel?

Tags: angular, input, ngmodel

I want to get data from a not exactly number of inputs on the right way in Angular 8 :

HTML

```
<input  type="text" class="form-control">
<input  type="text" class="form-control">
<input  type="text" class="form-control">
```

And I expect that fall in here:

TS

```
contato = { nome: '', tipo: '', fone: '', celular: '', email: '', skype: '', **prod: []** }
```

I have tried something like :

```
<input [(ngModel)]="contato.prod" type="text" class="form-control">
<input [(ngModel)]="contato.prod" type="text" class="form-control">
<input [(ngModel)]="contato.prod" type="text" class="form-control">
```

No results

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, explain your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure what are you trying to do, but if you want one input for every prod, you can use something like this using the *ngFor:

```
@Component({
  selector: "app-example",
  template: `
    <input [(ngModel)]="contato.nome" type="text" class="form-control" />
    <input *ngFor="let prod of contato.prod; let i = index;" [(ngModel)]="contato.prod[i]" type="text" class="form-control" />
  `,
  styles: []
})
export class ExampleComponent {
  contato = { nome: "", prod: ["A", "B", "C"] };
}
```